# Is only one $watch created regardless of how many DOM elements are bound to the watched $scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In the following code, is there only one $watch created even though the `<input>` element and interpolation of the double curlies `{{customer.name}}` create two different bindings to `$scope.customer.name`?

```
<html ng-app>
   <body>
     <input ng-model="customer.name" />
     {{customer.name}}
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As a follow-up, does the resulting callback to the listener defined in the $watch update the DOM and re-render those changed elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer to question 1:

There will be two watchers added.

Slightly simplified, a watcher is an object that is added to the scopes $$watchers array. This watcher object has a watchFunction and a listenerFunction.

Even if you used `$watch` to register the same pair of watch- and listenerFunction twice, there would be two watcher objects added.

### Answer to question 2:

It depends on the watcher.

Consider the interpolation in your example: `{{ customer.name }}`

The listenerFunction (the function that is executed when the watched expression has changed) of the associated watch object will look like this:

```
function interpolateFnWatchAction(value) {
  node[0].nodeValue = value;
}
```

Pretty straightforward. The listenerFunction will update the node's nodeValue with the new value. When Angular's digest loop is finished the execution leaves Angular and the JavaScript context, which is followed by the browser re-rendering the DOM to reflect changes. Again a bit simplified.

When it comes to the ng-model directive, it gets more complex, since it has a two-way data binding ($scope --> view and view --> $scope) while the previous case has a one-way data binding ($scope --> view).

The watcher added from ng-model doesn't even register a listenerFunction. Instead it performs work in the watchFunction.

I will not go deeper into the matter, but might as well put the code below (which can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1849-1870)):

```
$scope.$watch(function ngModelWatch() {
  var value = ngModelGet($scope);

  // if scope model value and ngModel value are out of sync
  if (ctrl.$modelValue !== value) {

    var formatters = ctrl.$formatters,
      idx = formatters.length;

    ctrl.$modelValue = value;
    while (idx--) {
      value = formatters[idx](value);
    }

    if (ctrl.$viewValue !== value) {
      ctrl.$viewValue = ctrl.$$lastCommittedViewValue = value;
      ctrl.$render();
    }
  }

  return value;
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to see the array of watchers that are not explicitly created through a $watch?  When I tried to log $scope.$$watchers I get null.

Comment: Yes, all watchers are added by $watch. Try logging just $scope and see if $$watchers contains anything. It might by that when you log $scope.$$watchers they have not been added yet and it will be null. Console.log is by reference so if you log $scope the $$watchers will be visible when they are added. If not added there might not be any on that specific scope.

Comment: Adding a setTimeout, did the trick.  Doing some experiments, regardless of how many interpolations I added to the page, there was only one watcher set-up (makes sense because just updating the entire $scope), however, every instance of the ng-model created a new watcher...is that because of the two-way data binding and necessity of the watchFunction requirement?

Comment: If you put multiple interpolations inside the same element, for example "<div>{{value1}} {{value2}}</div>" this will only add one watcher, since it's the node's combined nodeValue that is being watched. If you put them in their own tags there will be two watchers.

Answer (score 1):

Every ng-* and angular expression create internally a separate watcher. 
If you want to check how many watchers are created you could check for angular private scope property scope.$$watchers

Sometimes there could be a lot of this watchers for a complex app, with some performance issue, that's why library as [Bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) was born (in the demo you could find interesting code to check watchers)